# Wrong FieldRowPanel

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

Is my FieldRowPanel wrong?

```
padding = FieldRowPanel([
        FieldPanel(blocks.ChoiceBlock(
        required=False, choices=PADDING_CHOICES, label="Отступ сверху")),
        FieldPanel(blocks.ChoiceBlock(
        required=False, choices=PADDING_CHOICES, label="Отступ снизу")),
    ], heading="Отступы")
```

I am trying to do it in this place:

```
class ContentBlockThemed(blocks.StructBlock):
    theme = blocks.ChoiceBlock(
        required=True, choices=BLOCK_THEMES_CHOICES, label="Тема")

    padding = FieldRowPanel([
        FieldPanel(blocks.ChoiceBlock(
        required=False, choices=PADDING_CHOICES, label="Отступ сверху")),
        FieldPanel(blocks.ChoiceBlock(
        required=False, choices=PADDING_CHOICES, label="Отступ снизу")),
    ], heading="Отступы")

    visible = blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False, label="Видимый", default=True, help_text="По умолчанию - True")

    block_content = ContentBlock()

    class Meta:
        icon = 'user'
        form_classname = 'content-block struct-block pages-content-block'
        template = 'wtblocks/content_block.html'
```

Nothing is displayed in the admin, although there is no error

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid code.

- `blocks.ChoiceBlock` is only valid inside a StreamField definition
- `FieldRowPanel` and `FieldPanel` are *not* valid inside a StreamField definition, only inside the 'panels' definition of a model
- `FieldPanel` should be passed a field name as a string, not a block object

To control the layout of the edit form for a StructBlock (i.e. the equivalent of how you'd use FieldRowPanel in a panel definition), you need to define that layout as an HTML template and [set that template as `form_template` in the block's Meta section](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html#custom-editing-interfaces-for-structblock).

Comment: The documentation for customizing a StructBlock form is now here: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/streamfield_blocks.html#custom-editing-interfaces-for-structblock (I am not able to edit the answer directly because the suggestion queue is full).